# Getting the indexes of elements in one array based on the other

Tags: javascript, arrays

In javascript I have an array that looks like this:

```
arrFull = [[14, "Hello"], [20, "Hello2"], [40, "Hello3"], [62, "Hello4"], [100, "Hello5"]]
```

Out of these I add some elements in a new array like:

```
arrChosen = [[20, "Hello2"], [100, "Hello5"]]
```

How can I make a new array that contains the indices of the choosed elements based on the original array:

like `indices = [1, 4]`

Comment: `const indices = arrChosen.map(el => arrFull.indexOf(el));`

Comment: @ChrisG, this works only for same object references.

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes, but we don't know how exactly the 2nd array is created, so it might still work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the values of the arrays and get the indices.

```js
var array = [[14, "Hello"], [20, "Hello2"], [40, "Hello3"], [62, "Hello4"], [100, "Hello5"]],
    chosen = [[20, "Hello2"], [100, "Hello5"]],
    indices = chosen.map(a =>
        array.findIndex(b => a.length === b.length && a.every((v, i) => v === b[i]))
    );

console.log(indices);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arrFull = [
  [14, "Hello"],
  [20, "Hello2"],
  [40, "Hello3"],
  [62, "Hello4"],
  [100, "Hello5"]
]

var arrChosen = [
  [20, "Hello2"],
  [100, "Hello5"]
]

function findIndices(chosen, full) {
  return chosen.map(function(c) {
    for (var i = 0; i < full.length; i++) {
      if (full[i][0] === c[0] && full[i][1] === c[1]) return i;
    }
  });
}

console.log(findIndices(arrChosen, arrFull));
```